# I am having problem installing everdev tool

Tags: node.js, npm, everscale

does anyone have such mistakes running command. I try it on to Cent OS servers and have different errors. On first servers related to access problem describing in EVER docs, but on the enother server I have this error. I use the latest version of node. @EkaterinaPantaz

```
npm install -g everdev

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/everdev/node_modules/ssh2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/everdev/node_modules/ssh2/install.js'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the log, you have problems installing a transitive dependency `ssh2`, it uses an assembly from sources for a specific platform and this [requires a package](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/v1.6.0/install.js#L6-L15) `node-gyp` that is not installed on your system, try installing it first

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```